# pyspark agg() with groupby() is not working using pandas_udf

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, group-by, aggregate, user-defined-functions

When I am using one of min, sum, max, count, mean or std the pyspark groupby().agg() is working fine. But if I
provide any of median_udf, range_udf or quantile_udf user-defined function then pyspark groupby().agg() is not working(AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id').

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


@pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def median_udf(x):
    return np.median(x)


@pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def range_udf(x):
    return float(x.max() - x.min())


@pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def quantile_udf(x):
    return x.quantile(.50)


df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            ('2017-01-01 1:00:00', 1000, 'IC', 280, 11),
            ('2017-03-15 8:15:00', 1000, 'ICE', 280, 2),
            ('2019-03-27 5:00:00', 1002, 'IC', 260, 3),
            ('2019-04-01 11:00:00', 1002, 'IC', 220, 9),
            ('2019-08-07 1:00:00', 1000, 'ICE', 270, 5),
            ('2020-02-22 11:00:00', 1000, 'IC', 280, 3),
            ('2020-02-22 11:00:00', 1000, 'IC', 280, 55),
            ('2020-02-22 11:00:00', 1002, 'ICE', 280, 8),
            ('2020-04-08 9:00:00', 1000, 'IC', 220, 4),
        ],
        ['Date', 'TrainID', 'Traintype', 'Max_Speed', 'Delay']
    )

df = df.withColumn("Date", df['Date'].cast(DateType()))

columns = ['Date', 'TrainID', 'Traintype']

# agg_func working - min, sum, max, count, mean, std
# this is working
agg_func = {'Max_Speed': 'min', 'Delay': 'max'}

# this is not working
# agg_func = {'Max_Speed': 'min', 'Delay': range_udf}

df = df.groupby(columns).agg(agg_func)
print('Pyspark group by result')
df.show()
```

Is there any mistake in my pandas_udf functions? Where I have to change to make it work.

Comment: do you receive any error? what is the definition of "not working"?

Comment: I got AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'